# Why the compiler is reading first the internal term and then going out?

Tags: c

lets assume I've done return something1(something2(something3)); then the PC is first doing the internal term and then going to the next term which is something2 and then going to the next term which is something1, my question why he's going in that way and not going opposite, like this : doing first something1, then something2 , then something3?

Comment: I mean with "doing" , calculating ... ! the pc first doing internal terms and then he does return to the all term ..

Comment: How could it calculate the result of `something1()` first if that requires the result of `something2()` to be passed as a parameter?

Comment: The arguments to a function call are evaluated before the function body is entered

Comment: who said that?!!

Comment: Who said what? What MM said? Well _The Standard_ says that. And _The Standard_ defines the C language. Time for you to start reading this standard?

Answer (score 4):

Actually it does. It wants to evaluate (execute) `something1`. This has one parameter that it wants to pass. But that parameter is a function call, so it first has to call that function in order to get a result. So it calls `something2`. But this function has 1 parameter that it must pass, so it evaluates the parameter `something3`.

Now everything is fine: it can call `something2` with the evaluated parameter and then has this function's return value that it passes to `something1`.

So it does your "first something1, then something2, then something3". Except that it can't do the first without first doing the second, without first doing the third. QED.

Comment: what do you mean with "This has one parameter that it wants to pass" ? at first execution of something1 I'm not passing any parameter ..

Comment: Also So in that case we the PC is using something like stack or queue to save where he was, yeah? to get back with the value

Comment: When you write in your question "something1(something2(something3));" you are writing that something1 is passed something (the thing between the braces). So yes you are passing a parameter.

Comment: How the PC "remembers" where it was, is for you currently not important. You are just a beginner. However, to satisfy your curiosity: yes, generally a hardware stack is used to pass parameters and remember the return address.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works just fine.
Let's take your own example, you want to execute `function1(function2(function3()))`,

Now, if you break it down,
The program first goes to execute `function1()`, but `function1()` requires the value of `function2()`, so it jumps to execute `function2()`, and now `function2()` requires the value of `function3()`, so the `function3()` gets executed.

It just seems that the program is executing in opposite order but actually it is working in a regular way.

Comment: So in that case we the PC is using something like stack or queue to save where he was, yeah? to get back with the value

Comment: So can I say that the PC first calculate parameter of the function which sometimes it's directly or sometimes the parameters maybe be "function call" then after all is ready he calls the function?! how does he knows that's the parameter is ready directly ?

Comment: @Tony.M It is not that complicated, once the functions gets the value which is supposed to be passed, it executes it.